# Strange error, set<int>::begin() always returning const iterator

Tags: c++, g++, constants, set

Why is set.begin() always returning a const iterator and not a standard one?

```
35 int test(){
36     std::set<int> myset;
37     myset.insert(2);
38     myset.insert(3);
39     int &res = *myset.begin();
40     return res;
41 }


test.cpp:39: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘const int’
```

Comment: I had the same problem and funny enough, this code works in Visual Studio 2008. I only found out about this when GCC started complaining...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not returning a `const_iterator`, rather the key_type of `std::set<int>` is `const int`.

Remember that keys in a `std::set` are constant.  You can't change a key after it's inserted into the set.  So when you dereference the iterator, it necessarily returns a *constant* reference.  So you need to say:

```
const int &res = *myset.begin();
```

Comment: Ok, I guess that because of sets are ordered by templated type it needs to be const so that you don't change the value and is "unsorted"